# How to create a @Restcontroller that returns JSON from an array of users

Tags: java, spring

I am have been trying to solve this challenge for a while now. I am a JavaScript developer but have been trying out Spring Boot and Java and am running into an issue. In the below code I need to figure out how to write the `@RestController` logic to return JSON from the list of users created below in the User class. I am not sure how to go about doing that since this is all new to me.

```
package usersExample;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

@RestController
public class UsersController {
    /* Please insert your code here to make the tests pass */
}

@Service
class UserService {
    public List<User> all() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        users.add(new User("Bob"));
        users.add(new User("Christina"));
        users.add(new User("Steve"));
        return users;
    }
}

class User {
  private final String name;
  public User(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }
  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your expected output format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `@RestController`, the return value is already a JSON (spring-boot does the conversion without adding additional dependencies because it already include the Jackson library). 
You can simply create a method in your controller which will return a `List` of users. One comment about your code: use proper method names like `findAll()` instead of `all()`.

```
@GetMapping("/find-all")
public List<User> findAll()
{
      return userService.findAll();
}
```

**P.S.:** And in case that the code you've added is the same with the one you're running, I suggest you to create separate classes for `User` and `UserService`.

**EDIT**: The conversion of a simple object into a JSON object is done using getters. How is it working? Let's take your example:

```
class User {
  private final String name;
  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }
}
```

The converter will look for methods starting with the `get` keyword and set everything after that as an attribute name with first letter converted to lower case, this means that the ONLY attribute (because you have only 1 getter) will look like this: `name : -value here-`.

Now you may be asking some questions like :

1)

**Q:** What happens if you change your `getName()` method to `getname()` ?

**A:** Will work the same

2)

**Q:** What happens if you don't provide a getter to a field?

**A:** The field won't be converted to a JSON property

3)

**Q:** What happens if you change `getName()` method to `getMyName()` ?

**A:** The attribute name will be `myName: -value-`

So, if these have been said, if you want to change your JSON structure, there are many solutions:

1) Change the getter names (not really recommended)

2) Use the @JsonProperty annotation. E.g.:

```
private String name;

@JsonProperty("name")
public String thismethodwontworkwithoutjsonproperty() {
    return this.name;
}
```

3) Create a DTO object `UserDTO` and return this instead of `User`. And in your controller you can convert the user to an userDTO object.

```
public class UserDTO {
   private String fullName; 
   //getter; setter;
}
```

and

```
public class User {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  //getter;setter;
}
```

And eventually, you make the conversion like this:

```
@GetMapping("/getUser")
public User returnUser() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName("Stack");
    user.setLastName("Overflow");
    UserDto userDto = convertUser(user);
    return userDto;
}

private UserDTO convertUser(User user) {
    UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
    userDTO.setFullName(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
    return userDTO;
}
```

But I would suggest you to structure your application and add a `facade` layer which will make this conversion instead of creating `convertUser()` method in the controller.

Output:

```
{
  "fullName":"Stack Overflow";
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.I will definitely keep that in mind. For now this is how I was instructed to code the program.

Comment: However the code you wrote doesn't help me in solving the problem at hand. I still can't seem to return the data in the format that it wants.

Comment: I've provided some more details to your problem.. maybe it will help you to achieve what you need and understand how this `spring boot` works

Comment: Thank you so much. That actually did help me understand the logic better. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.